# Rotating content in JQuery 1.11.0 - all DIVs appear on refresh

Tags: jquery, html, css, rotation, text-rotation

I've set up a sample page to make this rotator script work:
http://twohatsconsulting.com/rotator/

The only problem is that when the page refreshes, all three DIVs appear before fading into the first DIV as it is intended.

My HTML code:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
       first
    </div>
    <div class="child">
        second
    </div>
    <div class="child">
        third
    </div>
<div>
```

My JQuery code:

```
var currentItem = -1;
var direction = 1;

$(document).ready(function(){
    switchItem();
    setInterval(switchItem, 5000);  
});

function switchItem(){
    currentItem = (currentItem+1) % ($(".parent .child").size());
    // hide the visible one.
    $(".parent .child:visible").fadeOut(500, function() {
        //now that the hide is done, show the current one.
        $(".parent .child").eq(currentItem).fadeIn(500);
    });
}
```

Comment: Set CSS for child elements e.g. `.child { display: none; }`

Comment: I tried that, but the result is that nothing appears at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is the first fadeOut takes 500 milliseconds.  It's during this first half second that all elements are visible.  Since you start with a currentItem of -1 you can use this to force the first change to happen immediately.  For example:

```
function switchItem(){
  var interval = currentItem == -1 ? 0 : 500;
  currentItem = (currentItem+1) % ($(".parent .child").size());
  // hide the visible one.
  $(".parent .child:visible").fadeOut(interval , function() {
      //now that the hide is done, show the current one.
      $(".parent .child").eq(currentItem).fadeIn(interval);
  });
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qpg8Q/) to demonstrate how that would look